# clang tidy incorrectly parsing doxygen comment

Tags: doxygen, clang-tidy

In code that uses doxygen comments, we have this:

```
/// @see @ref Foo::Bar()
```

This generates a "See also" section in doxygen with an explicit link to the `Foo::Bar()` class/method.

But with clang-tidy, this comment generates an error:

```
example.h:70:12: error empty paragraph passed to '@see' command [clang-diagnostic-documentation]
```

(First time I've see a code comment generate a compiler error!)

Is it really invalid to have a `@ref` as the content of the `@see`?  Or is the `@` confusing clang-tidy?